# Media Filesystem Type Validation

Tags: validation, filesystems, case, media, solaris

I am new to scripting and am at an impasse.  I am working on a solaris system.

In the event the operator selects the wrong option (e.g. placed a dvd in the drive, but selects cdrom) the system responds with the following:

"hsfs mount: /dev/sr0 is not an hsfs file system"

What is the simplest way to modify the case statement to determine if the selected fs is correct (maybe use input from error mesg?), and if not, treat operator input as an invalid option to force a new selection?

```
#!/bin/bash

clear
echo " Please select media type (1,2) or quit (3):"
options=("CDROM" "DVD" "Quit")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
 case $opt in 
      "CDROM")
           echo "Mounting CDROM"
           mount -F hsfs -r /dev/sr0 /cdrom
           break
           ;;
      "DVD")
           echo "Mounting DVD"
           mount -F udfs -r /dev/sr0 /cdrom
           break
           ;;
      "Quit")
           break
           ;;
      *) echo Invalid Option.;;
  esac
done
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (although untested):

```
#!/bin/bash

clear
echo " Please select media type (1) or quit (2):"
options=("CDROM/DVD" "Quit")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
 case $opt in 
      "CDROM/DVD")
           echo "Mounting CDROM/DVD"
           fstyp=$(fstyp /dev/sr0)
           case "$fstyp" in
               [hu][sd]fs)
                   mount -F $(fstyp /dev/sr0) -r /dev/sr0 /cdrom ;;
               "*") echo "Invalid media" ;;
           esac 
           break
           ;;
      "Quit")
           break
           ;;
      *) echo Invalid Option.;;
  esac
done
```